# Spatial regression: general nesting spatial model using splm package in R

Tags: shapefile, r, regression

I have a shapefile of panel data (multiple years of observations for each polygon). I am estimating fixed effects spatial regression models with this data. I used one year of this data to generate a spatial weights matrix based on the queen's contiguity neighbors:

```
spMini = dtaSub[ which(dtaSub$Year=='2001'),]
t2 = as(spMini, 'Spatial')
dta = as.data.frame(dtaSub)
neighbors = poly2nb(t2, queen = TRUE)
matrix_list = nb2listw(neighbors)

#Make shapefile into dataframe for regressions
dta = as.data.frame(dtaSub)
```

I have used the `splm` package's maximum likelihood-based functions to specify a spatial lag (assumes rho nonzero), spatial error (assumes lambda nonzero), and spatial autocorrelation (assumes rho and lambda nonzero) model. These are as follows

```
#Design a model
fm = nmPxlsD ~ cmps_13 + cmps_35 + cmps_57 + cmps_79 + cmp_911 +
  cm_1113 + cm_1315 + cm_1517 + cm_1720 

#Spatial lag model - estimates lambda
spatialError = spml(fm, 
                data=dtaSub,
                listw=matrix_list,
                model="within", 
                effect = "twoway",
               spatial.error = "b",
               )

#Spatial error model (SEM) - estimates rho
spatialLag = spml(fm, 
                  data=dtaSub,
                  listw=matrix_list,
                  model="within", 
                  effect = "twoway",
                  lag = T)

#Spatial autocorrelation model - estimates rho and lambda
spatialAuto = spml(fm, 
                  data=dtaSub,
                  listw=matrix_list,
                  index = c("ID", "Year"),
                  model="within", 
                  effect = "twoway",
                  lag = T,
                  spatial.error = "b") #"b" = "kkp" for a FE model


GNM = spml(fm, 
                   data=dtaSub,
                   listw=matrix_list,
                   listw2=matrix_list,
                   index = c("ID", "Year"),
                   model="within", 
                   effect = "twoway",
                   lag = F)
```

I cannot find any documentation on how to use `splm` to estimate a General Nesting Spatial Model (which assumes rho, lambda, and gamma are nonzero) using maximum likelihood. Is the function different from "spml"?